I'm trying to open anaconda navigator but it won't open
I just downloaded anaconda and the anaconda navigator is not opening. I tried to activate it through my command prompt but it is showing me this:
this is the error it shows me
From videos I've watched it meant to activate with no issue. I have searched around and people say I have to remove the double quotes, but I don't know how.

Try it from the anaconda command prompt which you should be able to find if you hit the windows key and then enter the name. In there, don't navigate to the scripts folder, simply enter anaconda-navigator and see if you get any other error message

It says "anaconda-navigator is not recognized as either an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Does conda activate base work?

What is that, please can you explain.
